# MVC jQuery submit form (without page refresh) from JavaScript function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, form-submit

I'm pretty new to all this.
I'm using ASP.NET MVC C# [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL).

I have an edit page that loads Authors and all their Books.
The Books are loaded via an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) call.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            LoadBooks();
        });

        function LoadBooks() {
          $(".Books").hide();
          $(".Books").load("/Books/Edit/<%= Model.AuthorID %>");
          $(".Books").show('slow');
        }
     </script>
```

This part is working fine.  The page loads with the Author info, then the Books load (a partial view in a DIV id="Books", just with the Book Category and Book Title):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Solution.Controllers.BooksController+BooksViewModel>" %>
     <% using (Html.BeginForm(null,null, FormMethod.Post,new { id = "bookform" }))
        {%>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Books</legend>
                <%int i = 0;
                    foreach (var book in Model.Books)
                    {%>
                      <%= book.BookID%>
                      <%= Html.Hidden("book[" + i + "].BookID", book.BookID) %>

                      <%= Html.DropDownList("book[" + i + "].CatID", new SelectList(Model.Categories, "CatID", "CatTitle", book.CatID))%>
                      <%= Html.ValidationMessage("CatID", "*")%>

                      <%= Html.TextBox("book[" + i + "].BookTitle", book.BookTitle)%>
                      <%= Html.ValidationMessage("BookTitle", "*")%>
                      <br />
                      <%i++;
                    } %>
            </fieldset>
     <% } %>
```

Now, on the main view page I want to have a link.
When the link is clicked I want to do a few things via JavaScript/jQuery/Ajax/whatever.
The first thing that I want to happen is to submit the Books form (id = booksform) from the partial view, then continue on to the next [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) function.  So, I click a link that calls a JavaScript function.  This function should call/do/execute the submission of the Books form.

I feel like I've tried everything, but I can't get my Books form to submit and process without a full page submit/refresh taking place.  (Note, when the full submit does take place, the actions I'd expect in the controller do successfully process).  I want the controller process/action to return nothing other than some kind of success/failure indication.  (I can then call "LoadBooks();" again to refresh the DIV on the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is how I do that with jquery:

```
function DoAjaxPostAndMore(btnClicked)
{
       var $form = $(btnClicked).parents('form');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  //do something about the error
             },
            success: function(response) {
                 //do something with response
                LoadBooks();

            }
        });

  return false;// if it's a link to prevent post

}
```

I assumed that btnClicked is inside of the form:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="DoAjaxPostAndMore(this)"/>
```

if link:

```
  <a href="/url/something" onclick="return DoAjaxPostAndMore(this)">linktext</a>
```

If link is not inside for the form you just have to use jquery selectors to find it. You may set id to the form and then find form like this:

```
var $form = $("#theformid");
```

Comment: What if they are clicking a link (not a button) that is outside the form?  How do I assign the form to the variable (var $form) then?  Thanks.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion assigning the from to the variable using var $form = document.getElementById('bookform'); Nothing happens when the link is clicked.

Comment: I updated my answer. getElementById returns javascript object not jquery object, use $("#bookform") instead.

Comment: HOLY CRAP IT WORKS!!!  I'VE SPENT 3 DAYS TRYING TO GET THIS STUPID SYNTAX RIGHT!!! I LOVE YOU!!!

Comment: If I could trouble you some more, on this line:  error: function(xhr, status, error), what are the xhr, status, error parameters?  Where do they come from?

Thanks.

Comment: Here (http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) you can find exlanation for every option on .ajax method. This is explanation for error: A function to be called if the request fails. The function is passed three arguments: The XMLHttpRequest object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "notmodified" and "parsererror".

Comment: +1 on the sentiments of love!

I found several references stating to use `$.post` for this problem, which didn't work.  When I get some time, I will need to read up on the differences between `$.post` and `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 3):

Is that `Ajax.BeginForm` that you need to use, not `Html.BeginForm` ?

Comment: No because you're not using the MS Ajax scripting, just using JQuery to submit a regular Html form.

Answer (score 2):

This is a "if it can help someone" answer, because I'm very late to the game, but you can also use :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
}
```

When the date will be posted, the page won't be refreshed.

**PLEASE NOTE**

You **MUST** add `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in order this to work. Be careful, in ASP.NET MVC5 template project, this script is **not** included by default, you must add it manually or add it via Nuget packet manager.
It is not related to `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`, which is included by default.

Comment: my badluck seen your answer today.

Answer (score 1):

Does your "onclick" JavaScript function execute and the problem is that full page submit/refresh happens ***as well***? In this case the problem is that you don't end your JavaScript function with `return false`.

Or is the problem that your "onclick" JavaScript function isn't called at all? Then it's hard to say without looking at the code... If you use JQuery selector - then probably the link isn't picked by the selector

Comment: Sorry this looks messy.  Is there a way to add line breaks in the comments?

<a href = "javascript: SaveProperties(); ">Save properties</a>

The function:

function SaveProperties() {
  $('#bevpropform').submit();
}

This works, but of course it submits the form and takes me away from the page.
I have not been able to find a way to get the form to submit without full page post.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href = "javascript: SaveProperties();">Save properties</a>
SaveProperties() { $('#bevpropform').submit(); }
```

As I said before, should be

```
SaveProperties() { $('#bevpropform').submit(); return false; }
```