# asp.net MVC 4How to capture json data from action and update dropdonwlist

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Background:
I have a asp.net mvc4 web application. In a page, I got a drop down list filled with file inforamation. What I am try to do is letting user click a button, and fire up a popup window in which, user can enter name and select a file to upload.  very similar to how we upload picture in stackoverflow.

[image]

Once the file is uploaded completed. In my action, I return json data which include filename and the uploaded time.

return Json(new { error = false, uploadedFilename = filename, uploadedTime = DateTimeOffset.Now }

Question:
Unfortunately, what the action returns is to print the json data on the page.

[image]

Could anyone help me with 
1. How can my view capture the json data and update my dropdown list instead of showing them on the page?
2. Should I use ajax (jquery ajax or ajax.beginform) to handle this?

Thanks very much
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as follows:

In Controller pass the json data:

```
return Json(new[] {
    new { id = "value1", name = "name1" },
    new { id = "value2", name = "name2" }
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then Make and ajax call to recive the json response and you can populate the dropdown as follows:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: //GET or POST depends on your need,
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    url: //Your URL,
    data: // Pass data if any,
    dateType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
             var list = $('select#id');
             list.find('option').remove();
             $(data).each(function(index, item) {
                  list.append('<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.name + '</option>');
             });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, futher question, how to sent file data via $.ajax?

Comment: You can serialize your form and can pass in data.. Have a look here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720020/mvc-jquery-submit-form-without-page-refresh-from-javascript-function